# ember initializer not injecting store into components

Tags: ember.js

I have the following initializer that is not working:

```
Ember.onLoad 'Ember.Application', (Application) ->
  Ember.Application.initializer
    name: 'storeToComponent'
    initialize: (container, application) ->
      application.inject('component', 'store', 'store:main')
```

The component does not have a store property.  I've tried numerous things like:

```
before: 'registerComponents'
```

But nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Your components will always be in some context (e.g. a controller), therefore you can access the store from that context by doing in your component:

```
App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    foo: function() {
      var store = this.get('targetObject.store');
    }
  }
});
```

However, it should be said that since components are thought to be isolated, you should rather pass data into them instead of creating a dependency from a particular store. 
That said, in case you really want to have the store injected into your components you could try doing it like this:

```
Ember.onLoad 'Ember.Application', (Application) ->
  Ember.Application.initializer
    name: 'storeToComponent'
    before: 'registerComponents'
    initialize: (container, application) ->
      application.register('store:main', App.Store)
      application.inject('component', 'store', 'store:main')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For more recent versions of Ember/Ember Data you should specify `after: 'store'` in your initializer, and remove the `application.register('store:main', App.Store)` line.